# Problem in installation of Ubuntu in Virtualbox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, uefi

I was trying to install Ubuntu 32 bits in Virtualbox but the following error occurred

> this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu unable to boot please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

Then I activated EFI in the settings. The previous error message disappeared but I got another page:

> UEFI interactive shell v2.0.UEFI v2.31 (EDK IT.Ox00010000). Revision 1.02
>   mapping table ......

What should I do to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Look at these solutions, I hope they will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/cannot-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-due-to-this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/291690/how-can-i-run-ubuntu-via-my-vm?rq=1

Comment: these solutions are proposed for those who are using ubuntu 64 bits but am using 32 bits it doesen't help :/

Comment: Have you tried changing the version to 32-bit?

Comment: no am using 32 bits from the begining

Comment: The error you mention should only occur when booting a 64-bit kernel. Your Ubuntu .iso probably is 64-bit.

Comment: how is that!? i downloaded a 32 bits version and even in the setting i only find a (ubuntu 32 bit) to choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your iso image is 64 bits, you need to download a 32 bits "x86".
Good luck

Comment: thnxx a lott ^^ i did nd it worked at the first time but now i can't open it an error occurred :"amd-v is disabled in the bios (or by the host os). (verr_svm_disabled)" what does it mean nd how can i solve it plzz :)